# Неправильная работа рекурсии

Tags: python, функции, рекурсия, пароль, генераторы

Я пытался написать Python код, который будет подбирать пароль. Вот сам код:

```
import sys
password = input()
chars = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']  # список допустимых символов
sys.setrecursionlimit(100000)


def selection(a, ls):  # 1 аргумент - пароль, 2 - список символов
    for i in ls:
        print(i)
        if i == a:  # проверяем, является ли правильным
            print(i)
            quit()

    new = (z + x for z in ls for x in chars)  # создаем новый генератор состоящий из всех 
    # возможных вариация суммы элемента списка, и символа 

    selection(a, new)  # вызываем функцию с этим генератором


selection(password, chars)
```

Но почему-то он выводит только числа от 00 до 99, останавливается на секунды 3, а затем pycharm пишет:
Process finished with exit code -1073741571 (0xC00000FD)
Я ни как не могу найти тут ошибку, помогите если сможете

Comment: длина пароля значение не имеет?

Answer (score 2):

замените свой код

```
new = (z + x for z in ls for x in chars)  # создаем новый генератор состоящий из всех
```

на

```
new = [z + x for z in ls for x in chars]  # создаем новый генератор состоящий из всех
```

Comment: Интересно как это должно помочь? =) Там нигде нет попытки изменить кортеж

Comment: тем что после этого составляются все числовые комбинации и находится пароль

Answer (score 1):

Всё дело в том, что вы используете генератор, а генератор - не список. Он не хранит те значения, которые он обработал. При значениях 0 - 9 функция берет значения из списка chars, 10 - 99 вторая цифра берется из генератора. Дальнейший код просит генерировать значения, обращаясь к отработавшему генератору `new = (z + x for z in ls for x in chars)`. Если вы в своём коде зададите `new = [z + x for z in ls for x in chars]`, т.е. список, то код будет работать.

Answer (score 0):

Итак, вот переделанный код:

```py
from sys import setrecursionlimit


password = input('Пароль: ')
chars = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']

setrecursionlimit(100000)


def bruteforce(passwd, charlist):
    for bf in charlist:
        print(bf)
        if bf == passwd:
            print('Подобрано:', bf)
            quit()
    bf_chars = [i + j for i in charlist for j in chars]
    print(bf_chars)
    bruteforce(passwd, bf_chars)


bruteforce(password, chars)
```

---

Что я сделал:

1. Упростил `sys.setrecursionlimit` до `setrecursionlimit`, импортировав его в начале, не импортируя весь модуль `sys`.
2. Сменил названия переменных на более понятные и правильные.
3. Добавил приглашение ввода пароля и приставку `Подобрано:`.
4. **Самое главное!** Сделал генератор списка, а не кортежа, почему - объяснили в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1202148/494483).

<sup>Кстати, я работаю в `Pydroid 3` и у меня писало `Segmentation fault` вместо вашей ошибки.</sup>

Comment: `setrecursionlimit(100000)` это ведь всё-равно не работает. Максимальный предел рекурсии всё-равно будет порядка нескольких тысяч, в зависимости от конкретного интерпретатора питона. Где-то 1500, где-то 10000, если очень повезёт.